# Bloc not rebuilding after succesful state change?

Tags: flutter, bloc

my bloc consumer is receiving the data from my state but is not rebuilding my widget at all for some reason, i also tried changing the color of my text but that didnt work either.

```
class _NameText extends StatelessWidget {
  const _NameText({
    Key? key,
    
  }) : super(key: key);  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String name = 'Nombre';
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: BlocConsumer<AdPreviewBloc, AdPreviewState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is AdPreviewChangeState && state.id == 'name') {
            // print(state.props);
            name = state.text;
            print(name);
            print(state.text);
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Container(
            // color: Colors.amber,
            margin:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: ScreenUtils.percentHeight(context, .3)),
            width: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context, 11),
            height: ScreenUtils.percentHeight(context, 3.5),
            child: Text(name,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'SF Pro',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    fontSize: 24,
                    color: Color(0xff525252)),
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The way that it should work is once i type on the textfield it should change the text that says 'Nombre', the event is triggered everytime i type on the textfield (which it does).

As you can see in this screenshot the string is changing according to the state but the actual widget is not being rebuilt.

[image: Console]

Comment: Try defining your variable 'name' outside build method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think u are using it wrongly, u already have access to state in the `builder` callback, u will have to use the state from builder as it will get rebuilt every time the state changes(depends on if u have passed buildWhen for conditional rebuilds),

could be done as follows

```dart
class _NameText extends StatelessWidget {
  const _NameText({
    Key? key,
    
  }) : super(key: key);  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: BlocConsumer<AdPreviewBloc, AdPreviewState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
         String name = 'Nombre';
        
          if (state is AdPreviewChangeState && state.id == 'name') {
            name = state.text;
          }

          return Container(
            // color: Colors.amber,
            margin:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: ScreenUtils.percentHeight(context, .3)),
            width: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context, 11),
            height: ScreenUtils.percentHeight(context, 3.5),
            child: Text(name,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'SF Pro',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    fontSize: 24,
                    color: Color(0xff525252)),
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

do update the example with your Bloc if the suggestion doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Actually if figured it out that i should build new state for my state class if i want to rebuild my `bloc` code successfully.